# How can I tell Rails to use RSpec instead of test-unit when creating a new Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, testunit

I have `test-unit` installed and `rspec` installed (along with `-core`, `-expectations`, `-mocks` and `-rails` version 2.6.x). When I run the command `rails new foo`, it uses `test-unit` to generate the test stub files instead of `rspec`.

Is there an option where I can tell rails to use rspec to generate the tests instead?

Comment: A lot of these answers are about creating a rails app without minitest, then manually adding and installing the rspec gem. What would be more useful is an answer explaining how to include a flag to set it as default, or perhaps through a rails template?

Answer (score 278, accepted):

The following should work:

#### at command line:

```
rails new MYAPP -T # The -T option tells rails not to include Test::Unit
```

#### in Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

#### at command line:

```
bundle install
rails g rspec:install
```

Comment: I think some of those steps are out of order, no? This looks like this would work though if done in the right order. Please edit your answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: You don't need the `generator.rb` initializer, this is taken care of by RSpec's railtie. All you need is `rspec-rails` within the `development` group of the `Gemfile` which is enough to require it for the generators. You also don't need to generate the app with `-T`, you can delete the `test` dir and it will work.

Comment: Can you edit the code from g.test_framework = :rspec to g.test_framework :rspec

Comment: @RyanBigg: with -T option we'll have `"rails/test_unit/railtie"` commented out in `application.rb`

Comment: When you add the `rspec-rails` gem, it's important to put it under test **and** development, or the generators won't use RSpec even if you follow the above steps.

Comment: @februaryInk's comment above ^^ is golden

Answer (score 76):

Create your new rails application as:

```
rails new <app_name> -T
```

Or remove your `test` directory from your existing application:

```
rm -rf test/
```

Make an entry in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rspec-rails'
```

From the command line install the gem

```
$ bundle install
```

From the command line install rspec into your application:

```
$ rails g rspec:install
```

Now your rails application uses RSpec instead of test-unit.

Comment: 'bundle install' step was missing from that list.  Added.

Answer (score 10):

Once you created your rails application with:

```
rails new <app_name> -T  # to exclude Test::Unit
```

Add the RSpec gem to your Gemfile in the following way:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails"
end
```

In Command line write:

```
bundle install  # this will install the missing gems
```

Now you need to install RSpec by running:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

This will generate the following files:

```
create  .rspec
create  spec
create  spec/spec_helper.rb
create  spec/rails_helper.rb
```

I strongly recommended to read through all spec_helper and rails_helper  comments to get a good understanding of what each option does.

Once everything is set you can run all your tests with:

```
bundle exec rspec
```

You can read more about the recommended spec_helper and rails_helper configurations on https://kolosek.com/rails-rspec-setup.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a new developer and I just made a rails flag (-rspec) to address OP's problem. It gets rid of Test::Unit and inserts the rails-rspec gem with a bash script. The script can be modified to help linux developers by automatically adding therubyracer gem or create custom flags and gemsets. (maybe specifically going to that gem line and deleting the comment)

Here's the gist && I hope this helps someone out there.
https://gist.github.com/MTen/8310116

Answer (score 1):

There's no native way to do this with the `rails` CLI. Generate a new project without `test-unit`:

`rails new rails-app --skip-test`

And then follow `rspec` instructions to integrate it into the new Rails app.