# How to tell Rails to stop using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to do I reverse [How can I tell Rails to use RSpec instead of test-unit when creating a new Rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728618/how-can-i-tell-rails-to-use-rspec-instead-of-test-unit-when-creating-a-new-rails)

I remove it from the Gemfile, but when I try to generate an integration test, it still tries to invoke rspec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make sure you ran `bundle install` after you remove from Gemfile
2. Do you have anything in your config/application.rb that looks like:

config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.view_specs false
  g.helper_specs false
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

or:

```
config.generators.test_framework :rspec
```

If so, remove those.

Comment: I had rspec underneath :development and :test, so where I thought I had bundle'd it away after removing it under test.. I hadn't. Thanks